# How to scan through user input and cut it into chunks in c++?

Tags: c++, user-input, truthtable

I'm making a program to evaluate conditional proposition (~ or and -> <->). As the users input *propositional variables* and *truth values (true, false)* ,and *proposition*; the program will go through the inputs and return the truth value for the whole proposition.

- For ex: if i set *p = **true**, q = **true**, r = **false*** and input: **p or q and r**.
- Is the anyway I can cut it into *q and r* first, then process and put it back to result (which is **false**), then process the next bit (*p or **false***) ??. And it has to keep cutting out bits (In proper order of Precedence) and putting them back until I have left is a single **true or false**.

  - And what I'm I supposed to use to hold user input (array, string) ???
  - Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: You hold the user input in a string (should be obvious, that's what the user enters). But as you *parse* that string you might want to transform the input into some other data structure. Data structures that represent the syntactic structure of the input (including precedence) are called *abstract syntax trees* (AST) so you might want to research that. Not sure for something as simple as this that a full blown AST is needed, but that's something you'll decide as you code. You might also want to look into any of the many parsing tools available that will help you solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think we need AST concept to solve this problem tho since it is too complex and it's just a starter lab from my discrete structure class. I will look up and research more on parsing tools. Thanks for your advice by the way!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks like this are usually split into two phases, lexical analysis and syntactic analysis.

Lexical analysis splits the input into a stream of *tokens*. In your case the tokens would be the operators `~`, `or`, `and`, `->`, `<->`, variables and the values `true`, `false`. You didn't mention them but I'd imagine you also want to include brackets as tokens in your language. Your language is simple enough that you could just write the lexical analyser yourself but tools such as [flex](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_mono/flex.html) or [ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) might help you.

Synyactic analysis is where you tease out the syntactic structure of your input and perform whatever actions you need (evaluate the preposition in your case). Syntactic analysis is more complex than lexical analysys. You could write a *recursive descent parser* for this task, or you could use a parser generator to write the code for you. The traditional tool for this is called [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), but it's a bit clunky. I like another simple tool called the [lemon parser generator](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) although it's more C orientated than C++.